# What were the liquidity requirements prior to Basel III?

Tags: banking, risk, regulation, liquidity

I am investigating the impact of enforcing the Basel III liquidity requirements with a focus on the LCR. I have found some information about regulations in fore prior to Basel III in Sweden and Germany. However, it would be very interesting to know if there were any European countries where there were **no** or **very little** liquidity requirements prior to Basel III.

Do you know of any such examples?

Many thanks!

Comment: There were requirements. You can find them in the Basel II regulations.